# Pandas strip value in column of every row with variable length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe that looks like the below:

```
| Name                   | Count |
|------------------------|-------|
| APPLE Apple            | 541   |
| BANANA Banana          | 56    |
| ORANGE Orange          | 345   |
| BERRY21 Strawberry     | 743   |
| GrapeFruit6 Grapefruit | 87    |
```

Where the name column contains 2 names with the correct name on the right. I would like to strip out the extra characters on the left (APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE, etc...) but not sure how to do it given that they vary in length (otherwise I would do something like `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str[5:]`)

Eventually I'd like to end up with the following:

```
| Name       | Count |
|------------|-------|
| Apple      | 541   |
| Banana     | 56    |
| Orange     | 345   |
| Strawberry | 743   |
| Grapefruit | 87    |
```

where the capital names/names with numbers in them are removed, leaving only the right most name. Anybody got some tip? thank you

Comment: series.str should help...

Answer (score 3):

Try [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[-1]
print(df)
```

```
         Name  Count
0       Apple    541
1      Banana     56
2      Orange    345
3  Strawberry    743
4  Grapefruit     87
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.str.extract` with this regex:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract(' ([\S]+)$')
```

Another approach:

```
df['Name'] = [x.split()[-1] for x in df['Name']]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[1]
```

or with apply...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unnecessarily complex after looking at these other answers, but the following could also work

```
dframe["Name"] = [re.match("\w+\s+(\w+)",str(element)).group(1) for element in dframe["Name"]]
```